# Forgotpassword function not working, sql, php

Tags: php

Not sure what happened but its suddenly stopped working...
I can enter the email and username (i know the credentials are correct) and get the message that it wont find any matching details...

The content of forgotpassword.php:

```
<?php
require_once("users.inc");

$PAGE_TITLE = "Forgotten Password";

include $PHP_USERS_HEADER_FILE; 

?>

<h3>Forgot Your Password?</h3>

<p>If you've forgotten your password, just enter the username and email address that you registered with, and your password will be emailed to you immediately.</p>



<form method="post" action="emailpassword.php">
  <p><b>Your Username: </b>
  <input type="text" name="username" size="35" />
  </p><p>
  <b>Your Email Address: </b>
  <input type="text" name="email" size="35" />
  </p>
  <input type=submit value="Submit" />
</form>
```

the content of emailpassword.php:

```
<?php
require_once("users.inc");

$PAGE_TITLE = "Forgotten Password";

connect_to_users_db();

$password = fnRandomPassword(8);
$encrypt_pwd = md5($password);

$sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$encrypt_pwd' WHERE email='".$_REQUEST['email']."' AND username='".$_REQUEST['username']."'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$sql1 = "SELECT email, username, password FROM users WHERE email='".$_REQUEST['email']."' AND username='".$_REQUEST['username']."'";
$query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
if ($query1 && (mysql_num_rows($query1) > 0)) {

  while (list($email,$username) = mysql_fetch_row($query1)) {
    mail($email, "Your Password", "Below is the username and password information you requested.\n\nUsername: '$username'\nPassword: '$password'.\n\n","From: $WEB_MASTER <$WEB_MASTER_EMAIL>\n");

}
}


include $PHP_USERS_HEADER_FILE; 

?>

<h3>Forgot Your Password?</h3>

<?

echo "<p>";

//if ($query && mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) { 
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) { 

?>

<p>We've emailed your password. You should receive it within a minute. If you don't, please send mail to the <a href="mailto:<?=$WEB_MASTER_EMAIL?>"><?=$WEB_MASTER?></a>.</p>

<?php

} else { 

?>

<p>We could not find an email and username corresponding with the email address and username you entered. Perhaps you registered with a different email address/username. Use the form below to try again.</p>



<form method="post" action="emailpassword.php">
  <p><b>Your Username: </b>
  <input type="text" name="username" size="35" />
  </p><p>
  <b>Your Email Address:</b>
  <input type="text" name="email" size="35" />
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<p>If you believe you have not registered before, you are welcome to sign up now with the following form:</br>
      <?php include 'fragments/requestaccont.htm';?>

<?php

}

?>
```

Is there some outdated coding here or something?

Comment: vulnerable to sql injection, uses old mysql_ . So yes outdated and dangerous. should be updated to new stuff pdo, etc..  But to debug immediate problem. print out the generated sql and run it by hand to compare against the DB.  Tis possible some extra chars /spaces are getting in there.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. You might want to use `mysqli` or `PDO`. As for your questions; does your code throw any exceptions or shows any errors?

Comment: You guys need to speak noob language so i understand :P
I get no errors except the part that it wont work and just gives the users "We could not find an email and username corresponding with the email address..."

So if there is a solution to just make it work for now it would help me until ive figured out how to change it :P

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? You're not doing any MySQL error checking.

Comment: whats funny is that i right now got a ton of emails with new passwords.... even tho i got the message about it not corresponding...  hmm... 

So seems like it works afterall...   :P but might be a good idea to fix the issues so will gladly take advice

Comment: @JayBlanchard

[Tue Nov 25 07:25:00 2014] [error] File do not exist errors....

but the forgot password function seems to send out emails after a while tho...   strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stopt working because you changed the line which checks the query. Now it will e-mail a new password and displays the 'not found' message.

You are using `mysql_affected_rows()` but the last query was a `SELECT` query which doesn't effect rows. Change the line:

```
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
```

Into this line:

```
if ($query1 && (mysql_num_rows($query1) > 0)) {
```

Also listen to Doon, `mysql_*` is deprecated.